# TextView in ConstraintLayout causes parent to shrink

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am having an issue to correctly position TextView inside ConstraintLayout, which represents an item layout inside RecyclerView.

The simple item layout consists of and image aligned to parent's star, small subtile text and the title text (`titleStr`) which causes the alignment issue. `titleStr` should reside between image and parent's end.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="140dp"
android:background="@color/white"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:paddingStart="8dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
android:paddingEnd="8dp"
android:paddingBottom="16dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageItem"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/banner_placeholder"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

<com.starcut.taskupeto.common.TextViewCustom
    android:id="@+id/subTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:fontName="AvenirLTStd-Roman.ttf"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageItem"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="4h ago" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/titleStr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageItem"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/subTitle"
    tools:text="Article title. This title can be big. How big you ask? Who knows?" />
```

If I set `layout_width` to `0dp` and constraints `start` to image's end, `end` to parent's end, parent is wrapping it's contents.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuqUs.jpg)

Another try is to set `layout_width` to `wrap_content` and use `layout_constrainedWidth="true"`. In this case text partially exceeds it's parent width. and If the title is a short text parent again wraps it. `ConstraintLayout` version used: `1.1.3` .

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jF9r.jpg)

Comment: please share screenshot item view

Comment: click on the links, they are shared

Comment: please check below answer and accept if it's working for you.

Comment: it doesn't work, I've tried that as described in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on how your layout behaves in the `0dp` (match_constraint) case I suspect the problem is in how you inflate your `View` in the `onCreateViewHolder` of your adapter. If your call looks like this:

```
val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null, false)
```

that means you are not defining a parent for your view hierarchy. You should use the parent `ViewGroup` argument from `onCreateViewHolder`:

```
val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false)
```

Comment: That's true, the parent wasn't defined. It works fine now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

You have to set `0dp` for TextView and set end constraint like `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageItem"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/banner_placeholder"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <com.starcut.taskupeto.common.TextViewCustom
            android:id="@+id/subTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:fontName="AvenirLTStd-Roman.ttf"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageItem"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="4h ago" />

    <com.starcut.taskupeto.common.TextViewCustom
            android:id="@+id/titleStr"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageItem"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/subTitle"
            tools:text="Article title. This title can be big. How big you ask? Who knows?" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

output:

[image]

Comment: doesn't work that way either, causes parent to wrap it's content

Comment: have you try this?

Comment: yes, I've tried that, forgot to put that constraint in the example xml, will correct post now

Comment: check this using English language text only. Text cut because of another language.

Answer (score 0):

[image]please check below code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageItem"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/titleStr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageItem"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/subTitle"
        tools:text="Article title. This title can be big. How big you ask? Who knows?" />

    <com.starcut.taskupeto.common.TextViewCustom
        android:id="@+id/subTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:fontName="AvenirLTStd-Roman.ttf"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageItem"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="4h ago" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I have tried that, check the example image, I've uploaded in the post. Text exceeds parent, short text causes parent to shrink again